# About the first order logic (valid, Unsatisfiable, Syntactically wrong)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am in trouble , I searched a lot about how to solve this kind of questions but I did not get any answers.

I understand how can I know when the sentences is valid and Unsatisfiable in propositional logic, but in FOL I can't.

Can someone help me how can I solve this kind of questions? Because it comes always in the past exams in AI.

Let us have the following:

```
1- ¬(Speed(Processor(MyPC))=Speed(Processor(MyPC))) 
2- ¬ ∃ x ( Speed(x) = Speed(MyPC) ) 
3- Speed(MyPC)=MyPC 
4- ∀ y ∃ x (Speed(x) ∧ Speed(y))= Speed(MyPC)
```

Note :

```
    MyPC: 
    a constant symbols that represents my PC.

    Speed(x): 
    a function symbol that refers to speed of x
```

The answer for 1 is Syntactically wrong
2 is Unsatisfiable
3 is Neither valid nor unsatisfiable
4 is Syntactically wrong

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1 uses a function symbol `Processor` which is not in the logic signature. Hence, it's outside the syntax.

4 tries to equate a proposition with `Speed(MyPC)`. You can't equate propositions in FOL. Outside the syntax.

3 is not universally true for every function `Speed` and every argument `MyPC`.
For instance interpret `MyPC` as the natural $0$, and `Speed` as the successor function to obtain $\mathsf{succ}(0)=0$ which is false. Hence the formula is not valid. However, it is satisfiable: now interpret `MyPC` as zero and `Speed` as the identity function to obtain $\mathsf{id}(0)=0$ which is true. The formula has a model and a countermodel: satisfiable and invalid.

2 `∃ x ( Speed(x) = Speed(MyPC) )` is always true, since we can take `x` to be `MyPC`. This holds no matter how we interpret `Speed` and `MyPC`. Hence is it valid. (Alternatively, we can even show it is a theorem of FOL using a proof system, and then rely on the correctness theorem to claim it is valid.) Since formula 2 is the negation of a valid formula, it is unsatisfiable.